# Apache (XAMPP 1.8.0) access.log/Intrusion Detection Concern

Tags: apache, xampp

I have Apache (XAMPP 1.8.0) running on Vista Pro x64. A couple times now I have seen a pattern like the example below in `access.log`. Concerning is the "attack" seems to somehow shift from a public IP to a valid private IP on my network (happens to be the WAN address of one of my routers).

Two questions: How is it possible for the source IP address to change, and what happens if the "attacker" stumbles on a valid request?

I've googled this to no avail.

```
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.4/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.2.6/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:59 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:20:01 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:20:02 -0400] "GET  HTTP/1.1" 400 1060 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal situation, that public IPs (and local networks behind them) are being constantly scanned by hackers, and other guys like that tools and scripts. First time I look into my home server logs I was shocked and terrified after finding how many (thousands) of such nearly-random access attempts were made to my IP, which is external (stable), but private, in the meaning, that I use it solely for private issues and don't publish anywhere.

That's for your first question, about how it is possible. Welcome to today's world! :]

As for your second question, what would happen? It depends, if you have taken enough security concerns, like securing root user of MySQL with strong password or removing it at all. Having access to a valid URLs doesn't means that someone has granted access to service behind it. Use encrytpion (SSL) and strong passwords and you can sleep fairly good.

BTW: Though this concerns XAMPP, it is not purely development question. Consider posting questions like that to StackOverflow's sister project called "ServerFault".

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I don't think my question was clear (I've just edited it). The question is not "why I am getting random and frequent requests?", but "how is it possible the requests appear to be coming from a device on my LAN?" I am certain in reality the source IP is _not_ on my LAN. Makes sense on the other ("what would happen?") question though. Thanks!

Comment: Well... If you own that IP (in your LAN), then I agree. But, if this is just another internal IP in larger network, then I wouldn't be that sure. I don't know, like you, but I was just a bit shocked (terrified?) to find out, how many "script kiddies" running some hackers scripts, found somewhere in the Internet, just to see, what results might be, are out there, in my neighbourhood, just a few houses next to me, in the very same local network! :]